# Trianglular 2D Mesh edge/vertexes finding

Tags: c#, logic

I have a list of 2D points/vertex with it's identifier.
And a list of Triangles in each triangle we have 3 vertex identifier which makes up the triangle.
This triangles can overlap each other as well.

This Green edge points is what I want be it internal or external
Any logic to find the same would be greatly helpful.
If there is any C# sample or library you can point me to also.

[image: This Green edge points is what I want be it internal or external]

Comment: I would assume you have a list of vertices and a separate list of triangles, what [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh#Face-vertex_meshes) calls a *Face-vertex mesh*. It is not clear to me what you mean by "internal or external". But any kind of analysis of meshes probably from connectivity information, see *winged-edge* mesh in the same wikipedia link.

Comment: I meant to say inside hole type edges and outside boundary edges.

Comment: jonasH what you have shared is of 3d, I want in case of 2D

Comment: 2D/3D should not really make any difference, its just one less coordinate for the vertices.. What you are describing sounds like you are after open edges, i.e. edges that that only have one polygon.